# Optional field image and 'childImageSharp' as null | Gatsby, GraphQL & YAML

Tags: reactjs, graphql, yaml, gatsby

EDIT: I ended up creating a small reproduction of my problem and posted it to Gatsby's GitHub and I ended up getting some help there.
Here's the [link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22918) to that issue!

---

I'm sorry in advance if this issue was treated somewhere else but I couldn't find an answer to what I need.

I'm currently working with Gatsby, GraphQl and YAML files and I have multiple sections that I'm mapping over but some have images and some don't.
I defined my GraphQL by stating the image with childImageSharp

```
sections {
              title
              description
              imageHere {
                childImageSharp {
                  fluid(maxWidth: 600) {
                    ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid_noBase64
                  }
                }
              }
```

and I saw a solution that involved adding this to my gatsby-node.js so that the paths could be properly read from my YAML files

```
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions;
  const typeDefs = `
    type allProjectPageYaml implements Node {
      imageHere: [String]!
    }
  `;
  createTypes(typeDefs);
};
```

Now my problem is that some sections have the imageHere field and some don't

```
sections:
 - title: Title 1
   description: Description 1
 - title: Title 2
   description: Description 2
   imageHere: Image1
```

The error I get is **TypeError: Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of null**

What's my workaround this?

Comment: Are you sure the typeError is triggered by the graphql query and not by the js which tries to access the property?

In the latter case you could use deep property checking, something like:
const image = data.sections.imageHere?.childImageSharp

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a small reproduction of my problem and posted it to Gatsby's GitHub and I ended up getting some help there.
Here's the [link](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/22918) to that issue!

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of the filepath that ChildImageSharp is trying to reference. When I was getting this error, the img filepath needed to be corrected.

Answer (score 1):

for me, it was a caching issue try delete .cache, public, dirs, or run

```
gatsby clean
```

*UPDATE* 
if using netlify ci/cd, also need to add this into `package.json`

```
"resolutions": {
  "sharp": "0.24.0"
}
```

https://community.netlify.com/t/error-input-file-contains-unsupported-image-format-gatsby/10891/4

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `imageHere` as a required array of strings with this: `imageHere: [String]!`.

If it's actually supposed to be an optional image node, you might want to instead define it as the correct type (something like `GatsbyImage`, but I can't recall exactly what it is off-hand—you should be able to check in graphiql). That would look more like `imageHere: GatsbyImage` (no bang, no square brackets).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I took that in consideration and later changed my '[String]! to 'File' since, according to this [link on Gatsby's page](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/schema-customization/#feeding-remote-images-into-gatsby-image), it should be a File. However, it still fails on me.  
  
Actually now it fails on a template page I built out of this one. It seems that childImageSharp isn't taking my image path and assuming it as an actual path. Instead it's displaying it as a string.
Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: @ItzaMi Oh sweet, that's typically what happens when Gatsby's inference system encounters a node that doesn't resolve cleanly to a file on the system. Even if it's just 1 and the other 999 work, the node is treated as a string type.

Comment: so what's the solution for this? I'm pretty newbie to gatsby and it's the first time I encounter something like this

Comment: @ItzaMi You'll need to find out which path isn't valid. That's a manual process as far as I'm aware.